# Remote desktop to Windows instance not working -AWS EC2 Free Tier

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I am new to AWS and started setting up a EC2 instance.
I have setup a Windows instance with VPC and security groups in place.

But when I am trying to connect that instance via RDP, it gives an error :

Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

> 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
>
> 2) The remote computer is turned off
>
> 3) The remote computer is not available on the network. Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

Comment: Did you open port 3389 in the security group? Why include your instance ID? Your question doesn't appear to be programming related and will probably be closed as off-topic.

Comment: check every step of the installation documentation and carefully check which step is missing.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Comment: I opened the port 3389 in security group. I included the instance Id because on AWS forums people are mentioning the instance ID and others can access and check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common things to check when connecting to an Amazon EC2 instance:

- Confirm that the instance is **listening** on the desired port -- I have seen people launch a Linux instance, then try to RDP into it
- Confirm that the **Security Group** is permitting inbound access for RDP (port 3389) from `0.0.0.0/0` or (preferably) your specific IP address (with `/32` appended to the end)
- Confirm that the instance is running in a **Public Subnet** (which means that Route Table is configured to use the Internet Gateway). If you are using a Default VPC, then this will have been configured for you.
- Confirm that you are connecting via a **Public IP Address** that is currently associated with the instance

Comment: Though I have mentioned port 3389 and all everything by mentioning 0.0.0.0. but still not accessible. I would check it from other system as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time the EC2 is not accessible if you miss the below steps.

1. Ensure that your subnet's route table points to the Internet gateway
2. The EC2 Instance has a public IPv4 address or Elastic IP assigned.

Comment: Actually I didnt get where to check these things ?

Comment: You can check this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html#VPC_Scenario1_Security

Answer (score 0):

Verify that in the route of the route-table connected to your instance:
-you have a rule of a destination for 0.0.0.0/0 with the target as your internet gateway and
-it is active

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJwK0.png]